# How to use generic type to access type values in another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Im trying to use the input type of one parameter, to figure out the allowed types in the second parameter where it is used as the key of an object.

Probably best explained by example:

```
enum Feats {
  feature1 = 'feature1',
  feature2 = 'feature2',
}

type Features = {
  [Feats.feature1]: 'maybeThis' | 'maybeThat';
  [Feats.feature2]: 'true' | 'false';
};

function useFeature<T>(
  feature: keyof T,
  opts: { variation: { [key: string]: () => void } },
) {}

const a = useFeature<Features>(Feats.feature1, {
  variation: { maybeThis: () => {} }, // Works
});

const a = useFeature<Features>(Feats.feature1, {
  variation: { hello: () => {} }, // Should complain hello is not 'maybeThis' | 'maybeThat'
});
```

I want the keys in the variation object, to match the types for the corresponding feature in `Features`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a given `T` (which seems to extend `Record<string, string>`) to construct a *union* of all valid argument combinations. This union would consist of *tuples* having two elements. One being the feature `K` which is a `keyof T` and the other being the `variation` which would then be a `Partial<Record<T[K], () => void>>`.

We can use this *tuple* *union* to type `args` as a *rest* parameter.

```
function useFeature<T extends Record<string, string>>(
  ...args: { 
    [K in keyof T]: [
        feature: K, 
        opts: { 
            variation: Partial<Record<T[K], () => void>> 
        }
    ] 
  }[keyof T]
) {}
```

Let's see if it works.

```
const a1 = useFeature<Features>(Feats.feature1, {
  variation: { maybeThis: () => {} }, // Works
});

const a2 = useFeature<Features>(Feats.feature1, {
  variation: { hello: () => {} }, 
  //           ^^^^^ Error: Type '{ hello: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<Record<"maybeThis" | "maybeThat", () => void>>'
});
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYsCGAXAzlA3gKClAZgxYATsAIxQC8UA5HkkaVQDRa770BMF1tBx7TGAL4YMiAJ4AHYLDbFUlTNgDacJMgB0PeiQC6ALmoR4YgEbAAKgAsAlsipQAPoeNmrSKgG4WK-Bq199akRCMGB7Jxp4ABtkMK9BLwwcMBAAY0RrAHsQKDBY1V5gAB5zKGAAD0RQABNUACVgVMzCaqLkYOsQAHNGKHbCTq6APiGAChZ1SfhCLuQDNCgWZQBpKE6oAGtgMUycKHNApSXsE-9gA2Xe45OoTIkUecWb55OAN2nrJCyQAwAFaYy0SKDSaLRKSmWOl6owAlBQhlBXplrNURk8XlBhDcdOjBEotjs9gcMHC0MIME0QO0oPAyJQ8sACvQiky5GMCn5ZKReopER8vtlHkZTBYbHMoLD4ehBJjegB6OVQADqzQ2yCEMMSlOp8E49PyXJZXOQ7N8mi5JB5LHeAwFP3QUEswCiUUyBkl5ARZNlUAVUAAypZMmAotUoE0IBIovB1k6XZk1qgQJlEM4RVZbOE065LO4NR4gA)